# Materialized View: How to automatically refresh it upon table data changes?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper, materialized-views

Is there a way in Oracle Materialized views so that it automatically refresh itself when there are changes on the tables used in the materialized view? What is the Refresh Mode and Refresh Method that I should use? What options should I use using Sql Developer?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can define a Materialized View with `ON COMMIT`, e.g.:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW sales_mv
   BUILD IMMEDIATE
   REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
   AS SELECT t.calendar_year, p.prod_id ... FROM ...
```

In this case after every commit the MV is refreshed, provided the last transaction was done on master table, of course.
Since refresh is done after each commit it is strongly recommendd to use `FAST REFRESH`, rather than `COMPLETE` this would last too long.

You have several restrictions and pre-conditions in order to use `FAST REFRESH`, check Oracle documentation: [CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW, FAST Clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6002.htm#sthref4692) for details.

Comment: in case of: ORA-23413: Table Does Not Have A Materialized View Log, run: CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON MY_TABLE;

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to 'automatically' replicate the changes to the m.view right after they are made. But there are ways to use FAST (incremental) refresh on demand, you'd only have to schedule a job for the m.view or and m.view group to do the refresh. You can also use m.view log to keep track of all the dml and the have it propagated to the m.view with a fast refresh on a remote database through the db link.

If you need the changes to be replicated as soon as they are made, then I recommend using golden gate or streams (if you don't want do license GG). Just beware that oracle discontinued support for streams in favor of Golden Gate, so if you have any issues, you're on your own. But anyway, it's a pretty solid replication tool, once you get the hang of it.